# What is the difference between get() and invoke() in Java 7's ForkJoinTask?

Tags: java, fork, java-7, executorservice, fork-join

Here is the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) for both:

1. get(): Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then
   retrieves its result.
2. invoke(): Commences performing this task,
   awaits its completion if necessary, and returns its result, or
   throws an (unchecked) RuntimeException or Error if the underlying
   computation did so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get() supports interruptible and/or timed waits for completion and report results using Future conventions. 
Method invoke() is semantically equivalent to fork(); join() but always attempts to begin execution in the current thread.

Comment: If I don't care about timing/interruptions and I know for sure my get() call won't thrown an ExecutionException should I just use invoke() then or does invoke() have some other downsides? Which one is better performance wise - my use case involves submitting thousands of I/O bound ForkJoinTasks to a static ForkJoinPool and I have to decide whether I should call get() or invoke() on the ForkJoinTask returned by the submit() method of the ForkJoinPool.

Comment: Wait a minute! ForkJoinTask has this restriction "Tasks should also not perform blocking IO". If you know about this restriction and still want to go ahead, considering performance as your main criteria, I would suggest to use get() as this will be executed directly by the pool, unlike invoke() where it would first attempt to invoke execution on current thread.